# SQL Server merge multiple rows into one column

Tags: sql-server, merge, pivot

I'm trying to merge multiple rows into one column.
I have a table:

```
COST_ID PRICE_ID PRICE_TIER   COST
1        4         1        850.00
2        4         2        950.00 
3        4         3        1000.00
4        7         1        250.00
5        7         2        275.00
6        7         3        300.00
```

And I want to the output one row for each price_id, it should look something like this:

```
ID PriceID C1ID C1Cost   C2ID  C2Cost C3ID  C3Cost
1    4      1    850.00    2   950.00   3    1000.00
2    7      4    250.00    5   275.00   6    300.00
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should provide better formatting for your tables, so they actually look like tables.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that I just fixed the format.

Comment: I'm just not sure where to begin getting all three price tiers to show up in one row. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd look at the questions under the [`pivot`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pivot) tag.  There are some that should be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, I think you just helped me figure it out. I'm going to try that now and this is the link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred solution would be using a conditional aggregate like so:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Price_ID) [ID],
        Price_ID,
        MIN(CASE WHEN Price_Tier = 1 THEN Cost_ID END) [C1ID],
        MIN(CASE WHEN Price_Tier = 1 THEN Cost    END) [C1Cost],
        MIN(CASE WHEN Price_Tier = 2 THEN Cost_ID END) [C2ID],
        MIN(CASE WHEN Price_Tier = 2 THEN Cost    END) [C2Cost],
        MIN(CASE WHEN Price_Tier = 3 THEN Cost_ID END) [C3ID],
        MIN(CASE WHEN Price_Tier = 3 THEN Cost    END) [C3Cost]
FROM    T
GROUP BY Price_ID
```

However this can also be done with SQL-Server's PIVOT function. However it requires a UNION because PIVOT does not allow for multiple aggregates in a single PIVOT.

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Price_ID) [ID],
        *
FROM    (   SELECT  Price_ID, 'C' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Price_Tier) + 'Cost' [Price_Tier], MIN(Cost) [Value]
            FROM    T
            GROUP BY Price_ID, Price_Tier
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  Price_ID, 'C' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Price_Tier) + 'ID' [Price_Tier], MIN(Cost_ID) [Value]
            FROM    T
            GROUP BY Price_ID, Price_Tier
        ) data
        PIVOT
        (   MAX(Value) 
            FOR Price_Tier IN ([C1ID], [C1Cost], [C2ID], [C2Cost], [C3ID], [C3Cost])
        ) Pvt
```

[Demonstrative SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5344e/2)

Comment: Thank you, my pivot was not as simple as yours. I also prefer the conditional aggregate, thanks for the help again.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has Pivot Tables, [Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/) usually provides a good introduction to SQL Server stuff - it's a place to start at least.

Answer (score 0):

If PRICE_ID and PRICE_TIER form a unique key, you can do something like this:

```
select
      row_number() over (order by PRICE_ID) as ID
    , PRICE_ID as PriceID
    , (select COST_ID from cte where PRICE_ID = t.PRICE_ID and PRICE_TIER = 1) as C1ID
    , (select COST from cte where PRICE_ID = t.PRICE_ID and PRICE_TIER = 1) as C1Cost
    , (select COST_ID from cte where PRICE_ID = t.PRICE_ID and PRICE_TIER = 2) as C2ID
    , (select COST from cte where PRICE_ID = t.PRICE_ID and PRICE_TIER = 2) as C2Cost
    , (select COST_ID from cte where PRICE_ID = t.PRICE_ID and PRICE_TIER = 3) as C3ID
    , (select COST from cte where PRICE_ID = t.PRICE_ID and PRICE_TIER = 3) as C3Cost
from MY_TABLE t
group by PRICE_ID
order by PRICE_ID
```

Comment: Glad to hear.  These correlated subqueries are one of the more traditional means of creating a cross-tab or pivot query.  You can always mark this as helpful!