# How to convert multiple rows on a single column in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two table with name disordersampletesting and diorder i want display the both table record on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

However this can also be done with SQL-Server's **PIVOT** function. However it requires a UNION because PIVOT does not allow for multiple aggregates in a single PIVOT.

Please refer
 [SQL Server merge multiple rows into one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685914/sql-server-merge-multiple-rows-into-one-column)